# Position an element to always stay in the same place

Tags: html, css

How can I position an element to stay in exactly the same place?

I am trying to pin the locations (which are images) on a map (map is also an image). Image of the map completely covers the viewport, and it can be dragged in all directions.

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="map">
       <div id="location"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#map{
 background-image: url("img/map_background.jpg");
 width: 100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position:relative;
 cursor: move;
}

#location{
 background-image: url("img/location_map.png");
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:100px;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mirta91/8L56bpny/)

Comment: Same place relative to the viewport or relative to the document or relative to the map image?

Comment: @Rounin Same place relative to the map image.

Comment: your code seems to be ok, unless there is something wrong moving the map

Comment: So what is your Q?!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I added the fiddle, you can take a look... the red square should stay where it is when I drag the map...

Answer (score 2):

Position absolute do the trick but you have to specify the `.wrapper` height and width to create a frame where your map can be placed full-sized to be scrolled.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2x6cLwcb/1/)

Comment: I edited my post and added the JSFiddle. I've also added width and height to the wrapper, but its still not doing the trick...